# initialize Unable to obtain CGLib fast class and/or method implementation for class : cannot be cast to net.sf.cglib.reflect.FastClass

Tags: spring, esper

I used Jfinal MVC for site build.

In testController Action, I add call to another static method which involed Spring&Hibernate&Esper Services.

Meet cast exceptions,not sure where is the problem happen. Actually the static method can start successfully when it called in JavaAPP Main but not in TestController.action().

```
2015-06-21 13:24:23,203 WARN  BeanEventType .initialize Unable to obtain CGLib fast class and/or method implementation for class com.algoTrader.entity.Transaction, error msg is com.algoTrader.entity.Transaction$$FastClassByCGLIB$$cf6c10d3 cannot be cast to net.sf.cglib.reflect.FastClass 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.algoTrader.entity.Transaction$$FastClassByCGLIB$$cf6c10d3 cannot be cast to net.sf.cglib.reflect.FastClass
    at net.sf.cglib.reflect.FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
    at net.sf.cglib.reflect.FastClass.create(FastClass.java:46)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.bean.BeanEventType.initialize(BeanEventType.java:358)at com.espertech.esper.event.bean.BeanEventType.<init>(BeanEventType.java:89)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.bean.BeanEventAdapter.createBeanType(BeanEventAdapter.java:142)
    at com.espertech.esper.event.EventAdapterServiceImpl.addBeanType(EventAdapterServiceImpl.java:429)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.init(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:312)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.createServicesContext(EPServicesContextFactoryDefault.java:84)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.EPServiceProviderImpl.doInitialize(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:458)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.EPServiceProviderImpl.<init>(EPServiceProviderImpl.java:84)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProviderInternal(EPServiceProviderManager.java:117)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider(EPServiceProviderManager.java:88)
```